# What happens when you pass zero arguments into a subroutine that requires them?

Tags: perl

Here are the relevant pieces of code.

One of the attributes of Slic3r::Print::Simple:

```
has '_print' => (
is      => 'ro',
default => sub { Slic3r::Print->new },
handles => [qw(apply_config extruders expanded_output_filepath
                total_used_filament total_extruded_volume
                placeholder_parser process)],
);
```

The relevant subroutine:

```
sub new {
# TODO: port PlaceholderParser methods to C++, then its own constructor
# can call them and no need for this new() method at all
my ($class) = @_;
my $self = $class->_new;
$self->placeholder_parser->apply_env_variables;
$self->placeholder_parser->update_timestamp;
return $self;
}
```

This code works, and I can't find anything online that explains it.
a few questions:

1. What value is $class assigned? I am guessing that it is assigned the calling Print::Simple object but I haven't been able to verify with a
2. I couldn't find the code for _new but if $class is a Simple object then it should be a subclass of Moo::Object, however I couldn't find the relevant subroutine within the package.
3. the call to placeholder_parser seems indicative that $self references a Simple object, however I don't understand how this delegate is being called. I thought that calling the delegate will call the relevant method from whatever is returned by Slic3r::Print->new, but this is calling the delegate before the method has returned a value. Morever I did a search and found no definition for a placeholder_parser subroutine anywhere in the directories for this program, or in the Perl libraries. So, what exactly is it doing?

Basically my mind is full of f%ck and I don't know what's going on. Also have to state that this program 100% works.

Comment: Is this the code you're working with?  http://slic3r.org/

Answer (score 5):

First of all, this Slic3r project violates basic Perl conventions.  Running `perl Build.PL` should only configure the build, instead it installs dependencies, builds and runs the tests.

The second thing to realize is the Slic3r Perl module is a wrapper around the libslic3r C++ library.  The Perl code may be calling methods defined in the C++ library and not the Perl code.  To really understand what's going on, get a copy of the [source code](http://slic3r.org/download).

> What value is $class assigned?

The first argument of a method call is the invocant, the thing on the left side of the `->`.  For class methods it's the name of the class.  For object methods it's the object.

For example...

```
package Some::Class;
sub foo {
    my $class = shift;
    print "$class\n";
}

Some::Class->foo;  # prints 'Some::Class'
```

> I couldn't find the code for _new but if $class is a Simple object then it should be a subclass of Moo::Object, however I couldn't find the relevant subroutine within the package.

Moo doesn't provide a `_new` method.

It took a bit of tracking down, but near as I can tell `_new` is a constructor created by the C++ wrapper code.  If you look in xs/buildtmp/XS.c you'll see things like...

```
XS_EUPXS(XS_Slic3r__Print__new)
```

This is the code which calls the Slic3r C++ library and turns the C++ object into a Perl object.  It is auto generated by [Module::Build::WithXSpp](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Build::WithXSpp).

> the call to placeholder_parser seems indicative that $self references a Simple object

This is probably correct.  `$self` contains whatever `$class->_new` returns which is probably a Slic3r::Print::Simple object if it is well-behaved.

> however I don't understand how this delegate is being called. I thought that calling the delegate will call the relevant method from whatever is returned by Slic3r::Print->new, but this is calling the delegate before the method has returned a value.

There's nothing magical about `new` in Perl.  That it's used as a constructor is just a convention.  You can have a fully formed object to work with before `new` returns it.

This is where `_new` vs `new` comes into play.  `_new` is the C++ object constructor.  It gets back just the basic Slic3r::Print object from the C++ library.  `new` then calls additional methods on that object.

> Morever I did a search and found no definition for a placeholder_parser subroutine anywhere in the directories for this program, or in the Perl libraries. So, what exactly is it doing?

placeholder_parser is a method from the libslic3r C++ library in xs/src/libslic3r/Print.cpp.  You can see the wrapper code in xs/buildtmp/XS.c.

Comment: I think you mean "left side of the ->" ?